# parallel process common plot

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plot

I am using doSNOW package in R and have a parallel process.
I want to create a plot that will be refreshed as each thread computes the datapoint so I can live monitor my process. How can I do this in R? The code below has to wait until all the threads have finished.

```
library(doSNOW)

cl<-makeCluster(4) # I have 4 cores
registerDoSNOW(cl)


a<-NULL
a<-foreach(j=1:10,.combine="rbind" ) %dopar% 
  c(j,j^2)

plot(a)
```

Comment: I don't know `doSNOW`, but it's certainly possible with [`doRedis`](http://illposed.net/doRedis.html)